# Display image before page load

Tags: ios, timer, uiimageview

I have four tabs in an ios application. I want to display image preview from view load. How can I fix it?

Comment: It’s not clear from your question what you are trying to do. Please provide more information.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg I want to display an image before viewload. But I want to display everytime. Like splash screen.

Comment: You mean, when you switch tabs, it shows an image before it shows the contents of the tab?

Comment: @ZevEisenberg Yes I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `-viewWillAppear:`, display your image. Then use a `dispatch_after` block in `-viewDidAppear:` to delay setting up the rest of your UI.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName"];
}
```

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(myDelayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Code to animate removal the image view,
        // adding new views, or whatever else you need to do here
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example ? I don't understand.

Comment: I tweaked my answer and added an example.